# A functor which preserves short exact sequence also preserves long exact sequence?

Tags: homological-algebra, abelian-categories

Let $F: C \to D$ be a functor between abelian categories (e.g. modules over the same ring), and it preserves short exact sequence, then is it also preserves long exact sequence?

Comment: Hint: every long exact sequence can be obtained by splining short exact sequences.

Comment: The answer is yes